# ERROR in pip when i try to install any package using pip in site.py

Tags: python, pip, package

hey when i try to use pip i got this error any solution

Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 617, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 604, in main
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 387, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 226, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 179, in addpackage
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1401: character maps to <undefined>
PS C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages> pip
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 617, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 604, in main
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 387, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 226, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 179, in addpackage
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1401: character maps to <undefined>
PS C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages> pip 
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 617, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 604, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 387, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 226, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 179, in addpackage
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1401: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Does https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#ensurepip point you to solution of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In case of problems with pip it is possible to reinstall pip using information available at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#ensurepip

```
Your options are: 
ensurepip
Python comes with an ensurepip module1, which can install pip in a Python environment.

Windows
    py -m ensurepip --upgrade
More details about how ensurepip works and how it can be used, is available in the standard library documentation.

get-pip.py
This is a Python script that uses some bootstrapping logic to install pip.

Download the script, from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py.

Open a terminal/command prompt, cd to the folder containing the get-pip.py file and run:
Windows
    py get-pip.py
```